# How to quit one level of imported package

Tags: haskell, ghci

In haskell interactive mode, ghci.

If I have imported one package, such as: `import Data.List`

I went to `Prelude Data.List>`

My question is, how to get back to "Prelude"

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GHCi "meta" commands begin with `:`. One of them, `:modules` (`:m` for short) lets you modify the currently loaded modules. `:m` by itself will reset all of the loaded modules returning you to `Prelude>`.

You can also use `:m +MODULE` to "add" the module `MODULE` or `:m -MODULE` to remove the module `MODULE`.